# Trigonometric Functions using factorisation and small angle identities

Tags: trigonometry, factoring

The function $f(x)=\sin3x - \sin2x + \sin x$ is defined for the domain $0 \le x \le \frac\pi2$.

a) By method of factorisation, show that $f(x) = \sin2x(2\cos x - 1)$.

b) Hence solve the equation $f(x) = 0$ using the given domain.

c) Using small angles identities, approximate the value of $f(0.1)$.

After a while I got through with part

a) show that $f(x) = \sin2x(2\cos x - 1)$

$\sin3x - \sin2x + \sin x$

$= \sin(2x + x) - \sin2x + \sin x$

$= \sin2x\cos{x} + \cos2x\sin x - \sin2x + \sin x$

$= \sin2x \cos x + (2\cos^2x -1)\sin x - \sin2x + \sin x$

$= \sin2x\cos x + 2\cos^2x\sin x - \sin x - \sin2x + \sin x$

$= \sin2x\cos x + 2\cos^2x\sin x - \sin2x$

$= \sin2x\cos x + 2\sin x\cos^2x - 2\sin x\cos x$

$= \sin2x\cos x + 2\sin x\cos x(\cos x - 1)$

$= \sin2x\cos x + \sin2x(\cos x - 1)$

$= \sin2x(\cos x + \cos x -1)$

$=\sin2x(2\cos x-1)$

For part b) *Not sure if right*

$=> \sin2x(2\cos x - 1) = 0$

$2\cos x - 1 = 0$

$2\cos x = 1$

$\cos x = \frac{1}{2}$

x = 60 degrees or $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

$(a)$ Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas,

$$\sin3x+\sin x=2\sin2x\cos x$$

$(b)$  $$\sin2x(1-2\cos x)=0\implies$$

either $\displaystyle\sin2x=0\implies2x=n\pi\iff x=\frac{n\pi}2$ where $n$ is any integer (Find proper value of $n$)

or  $\displaystyle1-2\cos x=0\iff\cos x=\frac12=\cos\frac\pi3\implies x=2m\pi\pm\frac\pi3$ where $m$ is any integer (Find proper value of $m$)

or both are zero (show this is not possible)

$(c)$ Using [Power Series](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Power_Series_for_Cosine_and_Sine) for Sine, $$\sin y\approx y-\frac{y^3}{3!}$$ for small $y$